# Write a MIPS program that tests if a number is a power of two

Tags: loops, mips

Write a MIPS program that tests if a number is a power of two. Set register $t0 to some value in SPIM and use this for testing power of two. The program will generate output in console.

35 is not a power of two.

256 is a power of two.

So far, I have this

```
    .data

    spc1:   .asciiz " "
    nl:     .asciiz "\n"
    tb:     .asciiz "\t"
    msg1:   .asciiz "is not a power of two."
    msg2:   .asciiz "is a power of two."

    .text    # "text section" code and read-only data

    .globl main # declare `main' as a global symbol

    main:   #sra $t1, $t0, 1
    li $t1, 1
    loop:   beq $t0, $t1, end
    sra $t0, $t0, 1
    j loop
    end:    la $a0, msg2
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    addi $v0, $0, 10
    syscall
```

I set $t0 in the simulator so that works fine. But no matter what number I set it to, I get "is a power of two". I'm using shift left but this keeps giving me the wrong answer. How do I use shift correctly to answer this problem?

Comment: `sra` is shift right, not shift left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a much simpler way to test if a number is a power of 2. In C pseudocode:

```
bool is_power_of_two(unsigned int number) {
    return (number & (number - 1)) == 0;
}
```

This works because a power of 2 will have a binary representation of the form `000…010…0`, and the number one less than it will have a binary representation of the form `000…001…1`. That is, the power of 2 has exactly one bit set, and the number one less than it has every bit before that one set. As a result, a bitwise AND between these numbers will be zero, because they have no set bits in common. Every other pair of successive numbers will share some set bits in common, so a bitwise AND between them will not be zero.

(Note that this algorithm will tell you that 1 is a power of 2. This is correct: 2 to the 0th power is 1!)

Since this is clearly a class assignment, I'll let you translate this to MIPS code yourself. :)

Answer (score 2):

After you initialize `$t1` to one, you should be doing a left shift on `$t1` in each loop iteration.  The `$t1` register will be equal to a new power of 2 in each loop iteration.

You should branch out of the loop if `$t1` is equal to `$t0`.  This is the case where `$t0` is a power of 2. If `$t1` becomes 0 after a left shift, then `$t0` was not a power of 2.

Comment: Since we are storing in `$t1` a new power of 2 in each loop iteration, our branch out statement in case of `$t0` not being a power of 2 would be more correct
`bgt $t1, $t0, not` since there is no point of searching power of 2 numbers bigger than our input. 
 `beqz $t1, not` works fine as well but eg for $t0 5 we only need to check 0 2 4 and not 0 to 2^30 as we are checking.